# Zend framework - how to allow empty field for form element

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I'm using this construction for my element:

```
$freetext = $this->CreateElement('textarea', 'freetext')
            ->setLabel('Comments')
            ->setAttrib('class','input-textarea')
            ->setOptions(array('rows' => '2', 'cols'=>'30'))
            ->addValidator('StringLength', false, array(0,500))
            ->addFilter('HtmlEntities')
            ->addFilter('StripTags')
            ->setRequired(true);
```

I want to add an "allowEmpty" to this but can't find the correct syntax. I was hoping for something like:

```
...    ->addValidator('allowEmpty', false, true)
```

But this does not work.

**Edit**: I've changed the setRequired() to true - I want to allow empty string as an acceptable value on a require field.

Regardless of usage, how do I add this option to my element?

Comment: Could you just change your Validator to `->addValidator('StringLength', false, array(0,500))
`?

Comment: yes, but how do I add this option anyway?

Comment: i'm confused. why do you need to use setRequired(true)? if you set it to false and add validators, it does exactly what you want it to do: it works if it's empty or is correctly validated. if it fails any of the validations, form isn't submitted despite setRequired being false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$freetext = $this->CreateElement('textarea', 'freetext')
            ->addValidator('StringLength', false, array(10,500))
            ->setRequired(false);
```

Your code should already do that, the `setRequired(false)` method do what you're asking for, i.e. if the value is not submitted then validators won't be run.

Do you have any issue with the code you've written, some validation error messages or something else?

**Update**

> I've changed the setRequired() to true - I want to allow empty string as an acceptable value on a require field.

What is the semantic in `setRequired(true)` and allowing the empty string as a valid value? Or better what do you require if the element can be empty?

What you've asked in the edit is a no sense, because if an element is required it MUST have a value different from the empty string. If you need to accept the empty string as a valid value just use `setRequired(false)`. When you get form values with `Zend_Form::getValues()` or `Zend_Form_Element::getValue()` you'll obtain the empty string as result.

Anyway here it's the explanation of `setRequired` and `setAllowEmpty` [from ZF manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.elements.html#zend.form.elements.validators):

> Using the defaults, validating an Element without passing a value, or
>   passing an empty string for it, skips all validators and validates to
>   TRUE.
>
> - **setAllowEmpty(false)** leaving the two other mentioned flags
>     untouched, will validate against the validator chain you defined for
>     this Element, regardless of the value passed to isValid().
> - **setRequired(true)** leaving the two other mentioned flags untouched,
>     will add a 'NotEmpty' validator on top of the validator chain (if none
>     was already set)), with the $breakChainOnFailure flag set. This
>     behavior lends required flag semantic meaning: if no value is passed,
>     we immediately invalidate the submission and notify the user, and
>     prevent other validators from running on what we already know is
>     invalid data.
>
> If you do not want this behavior, you can turn it off by passing a
>   FALSE value to **setAutoInsertNotEmptyValidator($flag)**; this will
>   prevent isValid() from placing the 'NotEmpty' validator in the
>   validator chain.

Comment: I edited my question. I'm curious to know if it is possible to add this option to my element as I might find better use for it in another situation.

Comment: @Fabio I had same situation like @Owen. I had to check if one of three form fields was filled with data. I've wrote a custom validator that checked this, but he was not fired because I needed to add `required => true` to make validators work. But then field must be not empty before validators are fired. It is situation when `setAllowEmpty()` comes handy.

Answer (score 6):

> ->setRequired(false);

this is enough if you want to allow an empty string and save an empty string to database.

if you want the field to be optional and keep null value in database if nothing is given, add:

```
->addFilter(new Zend_Filter_Null)
```

Comment: Thanks for the filter. Saved my day after 3 years of your comment.

Comment: For everyone how comes to this point:

In Zend Framework 3 the class is called `ToNull` and can be set as a filter